# If $y =\frac{1}{x+1}$, why is $x = \frac{1}{y}-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have such an equation where I need to find x

$$y =\frac{1}{x+1}$$

And I know that answer is
$$x = \frac{1}{y}-1$$

But I did not understand how to get it?

Comment: Multiply both sider by $x+1$. What do you get?

Comment: If $a = b$ (and $a\ne 0$) then $\frac 1a = \frac 1b$.  And $\frac { 1}{\frac 1c} = c$.  So if $y\ne 0$ then $y = \frac1{x+1}$ then $\frac 1y = x+1$. (But you must figure out why $y \ne 0$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just manipulate:

$y = \frac {1}{x+1}$  and as a fraction $\frac ab \ne 0$ if $a \ne 0$ we know $y\ne 0$ so

Method 1) "flip both sides"

$\color{blue}{\frac 1{\color{black}[y]}}= $$\color{blue}{\frac 1{\color{black}{[\frac 1{x+1}]}}}$$\require{cancel}$

$\frac 1y = \frac 1{\frac 1{\cancel{x+1}}}\cdot \frac {x+1}{\cancel{x+1}}$

$\frac 1y = x+1$

$\frac 1y \color{green}{-1} = x+ 1 \color {green}{-1}$

$\frac 1y - 1 = x$

$x = \frac 1y - 1$.

Method 2) "multiply and divide both sides"

$y = \frac 1{x+1}$

$y\cdot (x+1) = \frac 1{\cancel{x+1}}(\cancel{x+1})$

$\frac 1{\cancel y}\cancel y(x+1) = \frac 1y \cdot 1$

$x + 1 = \frac 1y$

$x = \frac 1y - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\frac 1{x+1}\\
(x+1)y=1\\
xy=1-y\\
x=\frac 1y-1$$
Note that $x$ cannot equal $-1$ from the original equation and $y$ cannot equal $0$, so we can divide by $y$ without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying both sides of 
$$y = \frac{1}{x+1}$$
by $x+1$ we get
$$(x+1)y = 1$$
and multiplying the previous one by $\frac{1}{y}$ we obtain
$$x+1 = \frac{1}{y}.$$
Finally:
$$x = x+0 = (x+1)-1 = \frac{1}{y}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Take reciprocals an subtract $1$.